# I'm getting an ConfigurationErrorsException "Couldn't find constructor for class CustomListener"

Tags: system.diagnostics, tracelistener

This is related to custom a Systems.Diagnostics.TraceListener

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
        <source name="SomeTraceSourceName" 
            switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch" 
            switchName="SomeSwitchName">
            <listeners>
                <clear />
                <add name="CustomListener"/>
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
        <add name="CustomListener"
            type="CustomListener, MyAssembly" 
            initializeData=""/>
    </sharedListeners>
    <switches>
        <add name="SomeSwitchName" value="4"  />
    </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

This doesn't happen with the default trace listener.

I found this [MSDN post](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/298418/in-certain-circumstances-a-configurationerrorsexception-may-be-thrown-indicating-that-a-reference-to-a-custom-tracelistener-type-cannot-be-found-even-though-the-class-is-present), but ultimately, it didn't prove helpful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found it-- it took a long time.

The key was this part:

```
<add name="CustomListener"
            type="CustomListener, MyAssembly" 
            initializeData=""/>
```

When the intializationData is a blank string, it will look for a constructor with no arguments. As soon as I added the value for initializeData then the framework found the constructor.

The error should have said "No constructor with 0 parameters, maybe you need to include some initializeData"

Comment: dude. seriously. thx for posting this. saved me! exactly my symptom. solution fixed my problem!